# In magento how to include subcategory path too in breadcrumb of home page product

Tags: php, magento, breadcrumbs

In my magento site i have added my products under subcategory.i was in need to display the full path for breadcrumbs of my home page product image like **home -> main category ->sub category -> product name**.

So i have implemented this link [Full-Breadcrumb-Path](http://dltr.org/blog/magento/381/Magento-Force-Display-Full-Breadcrumb-Path). Now i am getting the breadcrumb like this **home -> main category -> product name**.Subcategory is missing from the breadcrumbs.how to get proper full path in breadcrumb.

Comment: check that product, may be you have assigned that product to main Category also.

Comment: Yes i have assigned the product for main category also.Because i have created a menu for main category with sub category in dropdown menu and in that main category menu page i need to show the products from each category.

Comment: That is the reason, it giving priority to Main Category.

Comment: How to achieve both conditions.Need to display full breadcrumb path for home page products and also have to display the products in main category page with full breadcrumb path